# Flutter filter list by dates

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am getting a Promo List from an API that has a `dateStart` and `dateEnd` field which returns YYYY-MM-DD `String` or `null` if it is empty. Now I want to compare/filter.

1- has dateStart=YYYY-MM-DD && has dateEnd=YYYY-MM-DD - is ok to render but if dateEnd == today or over then it wont show

2- has dateStart=YYYY-MM-DD && has dateEnd=null - is ok to render in the list as it may be a lifetime promo

3- only show in list if dateStart is today or has already passed

Comment: could you add a sample for your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume this is your list:

```
List sampleList = [
    {"dateStart": "2022-11-18", "dateEnd": "2022-11-22"},
    {"dateStart": "2022-11-20", "dateEnd": "2022-11-20"},
    {"dateStart": "2022-10-20", "dateEnd": "2022-11-19"},
    {"dateStart": "2022-10-20", "dateEnd": null},
  ];
```

so you can get your list like this:

```
var result = sampleList.map((e) {
      if (e['dateStart'] != null) {
        DateTime startDate =
            DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(e['dateStart'] + ' 23:59');
        DateTime? endDate = e['dateEnd'] != null
            ? DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(e['dateEnd'] + ' 23:59')
            : null;
        var now = DateTime.now();

        if ((startDate.isBefore(now) || startDate == now) &&
            (endDate == null || endDate.isBefore(now))) {
          return e;
        }
      }
    }).toList();
result.removeWhere((element) => element == null);

print("result = $result");//result = [{dateStart: 2022-10-20, dateEnd: 2022-11-19}, {dateStart: 2022-10-20, dateEnd: null}]
```

now you can use `result` to show your list.

Comment: I'm not familiar with flutter, but I noticed a discrepancy: `DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(e['dateStart'] + ' 23:59');` and `DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(e['dateEnd'] + ' 23:59')`

Comment: ``e['dateStart'] + ' 23:59'`` should be ``e['dateStart'] + ' 00:00'`` probably

Comment: @ChristianAbila  the reason I add 23:59 is that the OP wants skip the date that equal today, and when we convert '2022-11-20' to datetime format the converter add 00:00 because the hour and minute is empty and in isBefore function, because 00 is less than current hour the condition won't work correctly. In summery I add 23:59 to make sure the selected date is at the end of the day so can remove todays date in isBefore function.

Comment: @OMiShah no, check the comment above.

Comment: @eamirho3ein, I think you should read the question again since the OP want's to filter data into 3 type as mentioned. Or may be I didn't understand :p

Comment: @user3352042 was it what you want?